# getView() in custom list adapter not getting called by ListView in android (kotlin) project

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, listview

here's code of my DashboardFragment.kt (which is kotlin part of dashboard fragment ofc)

```
// [imports...]

class DashboardFragment : Fragment(), Runnable {

    // declared all variables etc. here's everything good.

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = DashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root
        val policy = ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        listReturned.add(ApiRes(content = "testing", author="around", timestamp=12, important=true))
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
        dashboardViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard, container, false)

        listVieww = view.findViewById(R.id.listVieww)
        adapter = CustomListAdapter(requireContext(), listReturned)
        listVieww.adapter = adapter
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)


        return root
    }


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
        handler.removeCallbacks(this)
    }

    override fun run() {
        val thread = Thread {
            try {
                makeHttpRequest()
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        thread.start()
    }

    private fun makeHttpRequest() {
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("my_api_link")
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                Log.e("HTTP_REQUEST_ERROR", "Request failed: ${e.message}")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                response.body()?.let { responseBody ->
                    activity?.runOnUiThread {
                        val gson = Gson()
                        val daaa = JsonParser.parseString(responseBody.string()).asJsonArray
                        val newList = daaa.map { gson.fromJson(it, ApiRes::class.java) }
                        adapter.updateData(newList)
                        Log.i("tp", adapter.count.toString())
                    }
                }
            }

        })
    }
}
```

dashboard.xml: (to save space and your time, only part with ListView)

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listVieww"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="548dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="222dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.341"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>
```

CustomListAdapter.kt:

```
// imports

data class ApiRes (
    var content: String,
    var author: String,
    var timestamp: Int,
    var important: Boolean
)

class CustomListAdapter(private val context: Context, private val itemList: ArrayList<ApiRes>) : BaseAdapter() {

    fun updateData(newItemList: List<ApiRes>) {
        itemList.clear()
        itemList.addAll(newItemList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        Log.i("componGetCount", itemList.size.toString())
        return itemList.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        Log.i("componGetItem", itemList.toString())
        return itemList[position] as Any
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        Log.i("componGetItemId", itemList.toString())
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        Log.i("componGetView", itemList.toString())
        val view: View
        val holder: ViewHolder

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.message_box, parent, false)
            holder = ViewHolder()
            holder.titleTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitleTextView)
            holder.descriptionTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.itemDescriptionTextView)
            view.tag = holder
        } else {
            view = convertView
            holder = convertView.tag as ViewHolder
        }

        val item = itemList[position]
        holder.titleTextView.text = item.content
        holder.descriptionTextView.text = item.author

        return view
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        lateinit var titleTextView: TextView
        lateinit var descriptionTextView: TextView
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have logs everywhere so now I know, that this adapter has right list provided and returns right value from getCount() (in my case 1 or 2, so it is higher than 0) so ListView should call getView() and other methods but it doesn't, it only calls getCount() and nothing else happening.

I tried doing

```
        adapter = CustomListAdapter(requireContext(), listReturned)
        listVieww.post {listVieww.adapter = adapter}
```

instead of

```
        adapter = CustomListAdapter(requireContext(), listReturned)
        listVieww.adapter = adapter
```

but in this case, it just where stopping next code to run and like requests weren't making, list not updating you know.

can't find any other possible solution

**EDIT**:
In my code this wasn't working because in onCreateView() I was returning other View than one that I'm getting ListView from.(I'm getting ListView from `view` variable, and at the end of method I'm returning `root` variable which has nothing to do with adapter)

So preatty silly mistake, sorry. Maybe someone somehow will fall into same mistake, so I'm leaving this post right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set layout manager, please add as below:

```
listVieww = view.findViewById(R.id.listVieww)
listView.apply {
    adapter = CustomListAdapter(requireContext(), listReturned)
    
    // add below line
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
}
```

Comment: This would solve this issue if I were using RecyclerView, but I'm using ListView so there's no way to set layoutmanager to listview. But apparently, there wasn't so much you could help me, cause there was like really stupid issue. 

Instead of returning in onCreateView same View which was this from I'm getting ListView, I was returning root which was other View. But I really do appreciate your help, thank you ;)